# why axios convert http request to https in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a get request in reactJs app given by

```
const response =
            await axios.get("http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:3002/api/products/allTimers",
                { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.authorization_token } }
            )
```

it gives me error

```
xhr.js:178 GET https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3002/api/products/allTimers net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

why it convert my http request to https. How to solve this
while there is no error on localhsot.

Answer (score 0):

You can set,

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

but this is highly insecure. You are disabling TLS validation for any process running within the server, so not a good practice.

However, you can try below as suggested by [Nickuraltsev on Github](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/535)

```
// At instance level
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});
instance.get('https://something.com/foo');

// At request level
const agent = new https.Agent({  
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
axios.get('https://something.com/foo', { httpsAgent: agent });
```

Comment: You added process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'; to the top of your code ? and is time correct on the computer?

Comment: You double checked `this.state.authorization_token ` header ?

Comment: yes bro.. and that's also worked on localhost. just replace the ip getting error.